# why is that $1+2+3+4+5+6+…. = -1/12$?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I saw a post in Quora that stated the above. I'm wondering how come we get a negative I know that the sum is approaching infinity. Does that mean that infinity means approaching zero ? No right? Because infinity in my point of view, just means increasing without bounds. Anyways. am I correct? I always though of infinity more of a concept rather than a number. If anyone can explain why is this, I  would really appreciate it.

Comment: You're correct, it does increase without bounds. Can you post a link to the Quora post?

Comment: This is related to the Riemann Zeta function, and how it can be used to evaluate some divergent series.

Comment: do you know the mysterious "google"?
https://www.google.de/search?q=1%2B2%2B3%2B4&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=TMwQWYy5EqHi8Af34o2wBQ

Comment: In a word:  No, this identity is false.  However there are some facts about the Riemann zeta function that some choose to interpret as this identity.

Comment: As a series $\sum_{n\ge 1} n = \infty$ but  $\displaystyle\overset{\mathcal{Z}}{\sum_{n\ge 1}} n = -1/12$  where $\displaystyle\overset{\mathcal{Z}}{\sum}$ means the zeta-regularized summation, completely changing the meaning of the symbol $\sum$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Zeta_function_regularization

Comment: A general comment: life is short ! Dont spend time on such mathematical hoaxes. There are so many beautiful "true" mathematics :)

Comment: Short, wonderful coverage of this topic by 3Blue1Brown (also tons of other cool math things on his channel): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw